# Is "asking for code" appropriate if I intend to offer bounty?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounty

I have one plugin which I have no idea how to implement into my app, and which would take a lot of time to learn. Would it be appropriate to ask a question which essentially requests that someone write my code for me, if I explain that I'll put bounty on the question as soon as I'm allowed to, and award it to anyone who gives me working code? I feel it would be mutually beneficial to everyone involved, especially to future users of the plugin, who would have a working example to look at.

Comment: Asking for _gimme teh codez plz_ doesn't make up a valid question. So no! Hire someone if you wan't to get code written for you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Loud and clear. Just for discussion's sake, though, who would it be hurting?

Comment: Such questions are simply off topic for SO, and would be closed even before you get the chance to bring up a bounty for them.

Comment: A question asking how to write an entire plugin from the ground up would most certainly be too broad, so it would be hurting the quality standards that Stack Overflow tries to maintain.

Comment: @user It would be hurting the site, just as regular code requests do. People would feel the rules don't apply when a bounty is involved; users would start answering bounty gimmethecodez questions to gain rep, setting a terrible example for everyone else.

Comment: you'd be better off trying to one at a time, ask 100 questions about how to write your FooBar, rather than 1 question even with a bounty.  You'd certainly learn more.

Comment: I see. Fair enough.

Comment: What about asking how to do whatever you want to do ? That question may be on topic (it depends on the actual question of course) and would possibly benefit other users.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I was going to post the code I've been trying to make work, and ask what was wrong with it and how I could fix it. But, I asked a question like that before with the intention of awarding a bounty to whoever could answer it, and it got put on hold almost immmediately. I was wondering if stating my intent to award bounty would help.

Comment: @user3739453 mind posting your question draft on Pastebin and sharing a link here ? And yes, the question shouldn't be asking for code. Having a bounty on it is fine, as long as you're looking for an answer that will help you fix the issue; but asking for "give me teh codez" is not on topic.

Comment: Everything said here looks like what I'd say, so I'll repeat none of it. But I will toss you a plussie for asking first, and being open to the answer.

Comment: There is an obvious way to get your code written, but it will cost more than internet points.

Comment: Why so many downvotes on this? Isn't meta meant for this kind of question? And although I had a pretty good idea that the answer would be in the negative, I still wanted to see a well-formed reply to it to confirm and elucidate my intuition on this.

Answer (score 30):

**If a question is not appropriate for SO, putting a bounty on it does not suddenly make it appropriate.** In other words, the rules are not suspended just because a question has a bounty on it. A question that just asks for code is not appropriate, and so should be closed.

Now, it so happens that questions with bounties on them cannot receive close votes *while* they have a bounty on them. However, questions that should be closed and have a bounty on them **can still be closed with a custom flag** that explains that the question should be closed but cannot currently be closed by the community due to the bounty and by making a case for closure. I raise such flags every week, and they usually result in the question being closed.

Comment: Absolutely correct! Although, sometimes a bounty can make a question kinda *look* appropriate, by temporarily preventing it from being put on hold. ;-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Imho, absolutely incorrect. You can express your disagreement on my next answer, if you wish.

Comment: My experience with doing exactly this for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829752/google-spreadsheet-script-to-copy-to-match-the-values-based-on-matched-rows-to) isn't great. Flag has been pending more than 24 hours now.

Comment: Moderator(s?) appear to disagree with this advice, and may decline such a flag with the explanation _flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention_. See my flag on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487804/how-to-remove-editors-from-protected-cells-or-permanently-protect-cells-in-googl