# Why can't I set a bounty for my question?

Tags: support, bounty

Why can't I set a bounty for my question?

[How to get decode this attachment filename with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985743/how-to-get-decode-this-attachment-filename-with-python)

What's the reason?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281546/3001761. That's a bad question as it stands, you shouldn't be bribing people to answer it with bounty!

Comment: @jonrsharpe what's bad about this question? Please tell me.

Comment: *"How can I decode this with python like thunderbird does?"* is much too broad. There are many existing questions and resources relating to Unicode handling in Python.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there is an example header. What is broad about this byte sequence?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I was able to answer it. The Thunderbird example just showed there is actual data in there to be decoded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have [3 active bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633961/guettli?tab=bounties&sort=active). You'll have to wait until one of them has completed before you can start a new bounty.

From the [help information on bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> - Users may only have three active bounties at any given time.